# How to scrape liked videos on instagram?

Tags: web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I want to create a software that will log in to an account I specified on Instagram, download the videos I like from that account and upload them to a different account on Instagram, but I do not know how to scrape the videos I like from Instagram.